# TFS Build and Powershell Post-Build Script

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild

I need to get a TFS build process working where I dont control the agent, or any of the drop locations.

I have a post-build script which is shown [Here](https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Scripts/GatherItemsForDrop.ps1)...but I dont know how to edit it to so that it preserves the folder structure across multiple project directories.

I know I need to edit the file copy itself, but I am unsure of how to go about doing this in powershell...

```
foreach ($file in $files) 
{
    #Do something here to create the correct path on the drop server
    Copy $file $Env:TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY
}
```

The end goal is that instead of having all the build dlls in a single directory, I have them structured in folders per project.

Comment: Which build are you using ? XAML or Vnext build ？

Comment: XAML.  The system has the Vnext build stuff locked out for some asinine reason that I didn't bother arguing with because I couldn't get an exception for it anyway.

Comment: What's the structure of the destination folder you'd like to copy from?

Comment: SolutionName/ProjectName.  There are quite a few projects in the solution, and I would like all the dll's and exe's to be properly sorted by project instead of dumped into a single bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a simple script to achieve the feature you want, you can update it base on your folder structure and requirement.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY -Filter *.*proj -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
$projectfolder = $_.BaseName
$currentpath = $_.Directory.ToString()
$copypath = $currentpath + '\obj'
$targetpath = $Env:TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY + '\' + $projectfolder
Write-Host "Copying files from $copypath to $targetpath"
Copy-Item $copypath $targetpath -Recurse
}
```